# Register Property as DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl called ChartView. There I have a Property of type ObservableCollection. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the ChartView.

The code for a ChartEntry is:

```
public class ChartEntry
{
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use this Control in another View and setting the ObservableCollection for the ChartEntries through DataBinding. If I try to just do it with:

```
<charts:ChartView ChartEntries="{Binding ChartEntriesSource}"/>
```

I get a message in the xaml-window that I can not bind to a non-dependency-property or non-dependency-object.

I tried to register the ObservableCollection as a DependencyProperty, but with no success. 
I tried it with the code from [WPF Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html#creation)

My code for the Attached-Property is

```
 public static class ChartEntriesSource
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartEntriesSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ChartEntriesSource",
                                                typeof(ChartEntry),
                                                typeof(ChartView),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnChartEntriesChanged));

        private static void OnChartEntriesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static void SetChartEntriesSource(ChartView chartView, ChartEntry chartEntries)
        {
            chartView.SetValue(ChartEntriesSourceProperty, chartEntries);
        }

        public static ChartEntry GetChartEntriesSource(ChartView chartView)
        {
            return (ChartEntry)chartView.GetValue(ChartEntriesSourceProperty);
        }
    }
```

This also didn't work.
How do I register my Property as a DependencyProperty?

Comment: your class is static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be somewhat confused between an `AttachedProperty` and a `DependencyProperty`. Forget about your `ChartEntriesSource` class... instead, adding this `DependencyProperty` into your `ChartView` control should do the trick:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartEntriesProperty = DependencyProperty.
Register("ChartEntries", typeof(ObservableCollection<ChartEntry>), typeof(ChartView));

public ObservableCollection<ChartEntry> ChartEntries
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ChartEntry>)GetValue(ChartEntriesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChartEntriesProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need `AttachedProperty` here. In your `ChartView` add the `DependencyProperty` like

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartEntriesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChartEntries",
                                            typeof(ObservableCollection<ChartEntry>),
                                            typeof(ChartView),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnChartEntriesChanged));

    private static void OnChartEntriesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Now you can bind your ChartEntries property :

```
 <charts:ChartView ChartEntries="{Binding PROPERTYOFYOURDATACONTEXT}"/>
```

Comment: Oooh, you're quick! :)