# How to set a Bindíng in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, binding

I've read some books ([galli](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/visual_csharp_2012/1997_24_002.html#dodtp6e036ecb-d644-4117-a420-85e8e6c693ca)) and did some research here on the site. The problem is I think I didn't understand it.

What I tried to do is to create a button of a custom shape (hexagon). When the user clicks it, it should change the Color.

After finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131637/binding-string-property-in-code-behind-textblock) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525185/how-to-set-a-binding-in-code), I created the following:

```
 public class hexButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public SolidColorBrush borderColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush fillColor {get;set;}
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public Point Location { get; private set; }
    private Hexagon hex;

    public hexButton() : this(50,0,0,Colors.Yellow, Colors.Brown){}    

    public hexButton(int sideLenght, int positionX, int positionY, Color border, Color fill):base()
    {
        borderColor = new SolidColorBrush(border);
        fillColor = new SolidColorBrush(fill);
        hex = new Hexagon(sideLenght, positionX, positionY);

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FillProperty");
        binding.Source = fillColor;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(hex.polygon, Polygon.FillProperty, binding);

        ControlTemplate t = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
        FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Polygon));
        fef.Name = "Polygon";
        fef.SetValue(Polygon.PointsProperty, hex.polygon.Points);
        fef.SetBinding(Polygon.FillProperty, binding); //doesent work
        fef.SetValue(Polygon.StrokeThicknessProperty, hex.polygon.StrokeThickness);
        //fef.SetValue(Polygon.FillProperty, fillColor); // works at least for the constructor
        fef.SetValue(Polygon.StrokeProperty, borderColor);
        t.VisualTree = fef;

        Style hexButtonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
        hexButtonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.TemplateProperty, t));

        this.Style = hexButtonStyle;
        this.Height = hex.Y_Max - hex.Y_Min;
        this.Width = hex.X_Max - hex.X_Min;
        this.Location = hex.location;
    }
```

I also have a hexagon class:

```
    public class Hexagon
{
    private int _Height;
    private int _Diameter;
    private int _SideLenght;
    public Polygon polygon { get; set; }
    public int Y_Min { get; private set; }
    public int Y_Max { get; private set; }
    public int X_Min { get; private set; }
    public int X_Max { get; private set; }
    public Point location { get; set; }

    public Hexagon() : this(30) { }

    public Hexagon(int sideLenght): this (sideLenght,0,0) { }

    public Hexagon(int sideLenght, Point location): this(sideLenght,(int)location.X, (int)location.Y){}

    public Hexagon(int sideLenght, int locationX, int locationY)
    {
        if (sideLenght <= 0)
        {
            sideLenght = 30;
        }
        _SideLenght = sideLenght;
        calcHeight();
        calcDiameter();
        location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
        polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.Points.Clear();
        polygon.StrokeThickness = 4;
        createHexPolygon();
    }

    private void calcHeight()
    {
        //h = (√3)s
        _Height = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(3,0.5)*_SideLenght);
    }

    private void calcDiameter()
    {
        _Diameter = 2 * _SideLenght;
    }

    private void createHexPolygon()
    {   //        0           1
        //         __________
        //        /          \
        //       /            \
        //      /              \  2
        //    5 \              /
        //       \            /
        //        \__________/
        //        4           3

        Point p = new Point();
        p.X = _SideLenght / 2;
        p.Y = 0;
        p.X = p.X + location.X + 2; // +2 =offset von StrokeThickness (siehe konstruktor)
        p.Y = p.Y + location.Y + 2;
        polygon.Points.Add(p);
        p.X = _SideLenght + (_SideLenght / 2);
        p.Y = 0;
        p.X = p.X + location.X + 2;
        p.Y = p.Y + location.Y + 2;
        polygon.Points.Add(p);
        p.X = _Diameter;
        p.Y = _Height / 2;
        p.X = p.X + location.X + 2;
        p.Y = p.Y + location.Y + 2;
        polygon.Points.Add(p);
        p.X = _SideLenght + (_SideLenght / 2);
        p.Y = _Height;
        p.X = p.X + location.X + 2;
        p.Y = p.Y + location.Y + 2;
        polygon.Points.Add(p);
        p.X = _SideLenght / 2;
        p.Y = _Height;
        p.X = p.X + location.X + 2;
        p.Y = p.Y + location.Y + 2;
        polygon.Points.Add(p);
        p.X = 0;
        p.Y = _Height / 2;
        p.X = p.X + location.X + 2;
        p.Y = p.Y + location.Y + 2;
        polygon.Points.Add(p);

        X_Min = (int)polygon.Points[5].X;
        X_Max = (int)polygon.Points[2].X + 2;
        Y_Min = (int)polygon.Points[0].Y;
        Y_Max = (int)polygon.Points[3].Y + 2;
    }

}
```

For later use (when clicking the button - property changed event necessary) I wanted to use this to reset the binding:

```
        private void SetBinding()
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FillProperty");
        binding.Source = fillColor;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(hex.polygon, Polygon.FillProperty, binding);
    }
```

I think the problem is somewhere in here:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FillProperty");
        binding.Source = fillColor;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(hex.polygon, Polygon.FillProperty, binding);

        //....

        fef.SetBinding(Polygon.FillProperty, binding);


1. Why is the binding not working?
2. What do I need to do to make it work?
3. I read somewhere (don't know where) that creating styles and bindings in code (behind) is not really recommended
    - What would be another way to do this?
    - Why is it not recommended?
```

Comment: I would recommend doing it inside xaml since one of the huge point of WPF comparing to win form is to separate out UI and logic code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Shaped Button in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532063/custom-shaped-button-in-wpf)

Comment: @Ash : Your right, the only difference is that I am unsing _Polygon_ instead of _Path_  and _Canvas_ instead of _Grid_ but thats not much of a change. And it works fine with that. However, is there a way to bind the _Path_ or the _Points_ of the _Path_ (so that I can redraw it depending on the _Width_ or _Height_ of the _Button_)? I dont see a _DependencyProperty_ that would fit... Can I create my own? If yes, how is it done?

Comment: by the way: if found [this](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html) really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very very basic level, binding is done by using the `DataContext` property of a UI element. For example, if you had a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
     public string FirstName {get;set;}
     public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

You can then use binding to bind these properties to UI elements without explicitly setting them. An example of this would be if you had a `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStack" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This XAML will look for any properties named FirstName or LastName in the DataContext that is set. So by setting the `DataContext` to a `Person` object, it can display the data we specify.

`MyStack.DataContext = new Person(){ FirstName = "Test", LastName = "Man"};`

This will then tell the StackPanel to populate those two textboxes with 'Test' and 'Man'.

This logic extends to any types of UI objects, such as `SolidColorBrush` for setting colours. If you extended the Person class to accept a `SolidColorBrush` for a `FavColor` property, you could then set the background of the panel by setting a binding for that too, i.e.

`<StackPanel x:Name="MyStack" Background="{Binding FavColor}" Orientation="Horizontal">`

However, as mentioned, you really want to keep your models (the objects that contain the data you want to display, like our Person, or a User, or a Shape, etc) and any sort of View information completely separate. To read more into how to do this, I would look into the Model View View-Model (MVVM) pattern, which focuses heavily on XAML data binding. There are plenty of good tutorials out there, I used video examples to help me get an understanding, so it may be worth searching for these too to expand your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FillProperty");
binding.Source = fillColor;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(hex.polygon, Polygon.FillProperty, binding);
```

That code creates a binding whose `Source` is a `SolidColorBrush`, and whose `Path` is `FillProperty`.

What that means is that the binding is going to go to the `Source` object, and look for a property named `FillProperty` on that `Source` object, and then it will pass the value of that property along to the `Fill` property of a polygon.

That's not what you want: `SolidColorBrush` has no property named `FillProperty` (nothing does), and it also doesn't have a property named `Fill` either. `Fill` is the target property, not the source property. What you want is this:

```
hex.polygon.Fill = fillColor;
```

It's not useful to use a binding in this particular case, because `fillColor` is a local variable. You use bindings for properties, so that when the source changes, the target will be updated (and/or target changes may updated the source, depending on parameters).

But for the sake of learning how `Binding` works, this should also do what you want:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = fillColor;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(hex.polygon, Polygon.FillProperty, binding);
```

I see some confusion about `Polygon.FillProperty` vs `Polygon.Fill`. `Polygon.FillProperty` is a [public static readonly `DependencyProperty` object which describes the characteristics of the Polygon's `Fill` dependency property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542262/424129). `Polygon` also has a regular property named `Fill`, which you can use directly as I showed above. It's a convention that the name of the public static readonly `DependencyProperty` object is the same as the notional dependency property, with a suffix of "Property", but it's not absolutely required.